# Passenger Max Requests on Heroku

Tags: heroku, passenger

It it possible to setup Passenger to use a [PassengerMaxRequests](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerMaxRequests) on Heroku? From what I can tell, Heroku requires the passenger configuration to happen within a Procfile like so:

```
web: bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT --max-pool-size 4
```

I tried `--max-requests` but get an `invalid option` exception. It also doesn't appear under `heroku start --help`. Any way to get this parameter (or any of the other parameters from the docs) working with a Procfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should follow the [Passenger Standalone Advanced Configuration](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#advanced_configuration) guide, and create an nginx config file (not apache), since it seems the standalone passenger actually just comes with nginx.

`passenger start --nginx-config-template nginx.conf.erb`

And then you should be able to set [passenger_max_requests](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerMaxRequests)